# FileReader in Java not finding the file

Tags: java, filereader

I'm trying to read a plain text file but somehow `FileReader` is not finding my text file. I checked the directory using `getAbsolutefile()` and `/Users/djhanz/IdeaProjects/datalab2/pg174.txt` is the exact location of the file. I tried `datlab2/pg174.txt` and  everything I possibly could.
Here is my code

```
public class Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new File("pg174.txt").getAbsoluteFile());
        Scanner testScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/djhanz/IdeaProjects/datalab2/pg174.txt")));
        while (testScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(testScanner.nextLine());
        }

    }


}
```

The text file is under the same project directory called `datalab`.
Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: So what happens when you compile/run this program? I suspect it doesn't even compile and that's not related to the file name.

Comment: Instead of just printing the `File` object, save it to a variable and use it in the `FileReader` constructor. This way you can make sure you are using the correct file. Also check the file-system if the file you specify really exists.

Comment: Use `Scanner testScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/pg174.txt")));`

Comment: *"same project directory called datalab"* --- `datalab` != `datalab2`

Comment: *FYI:* Just because `println(new File("pg174.txt").getAbsoluteFile())` prints `/Users/djhanz/IdeaProjects/datalab2/pg174.txt` doesn't mean that there is a file there. It just means that the current working directory is `/Users/djhanz/IdeaProjects/datalab2`.

Comment: BTW `FileReader` uses the platform encoding for the text in the file. One would need another class to specify the encoding/Charset.

Comment: thank you for your comment guys but it is still returning Error:(21, 62) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Answer (score -1):

Use `Scanner testScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/pg174.txt")));`

`FileReader("/pg174.txt")` instead of `FileReader("pg174.txt")`.

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(new File("pg174.txt").getPath());
        System.out.println(new File("pg174.txt").getAbsoluteFile());
        System.out.println(new File("pg174.txt").getAbsolutePath());
        Scanner testScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/pg174.txt")));
        while (testScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(testScanner.nextLine());
       }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: Why do you believe that file `pg174.txt` exists in the **root directory** of the file system? Question says *"The text file is under the same project directory called datalab"*, which means it's not in the root folder.

Comment: The questioner wrote `The text file is under the same project directory called datalab`.

Comment: Yes, and "under" means "not root", so specifying an **absolute** path to a file in the **root directory** (e.g. `"/pg174.txt"`) is certainly not it.

Comment: Yes.Then `Scanner testScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/pg174.txt").getAbsoluteFile())));` should work as per my answer.

Comment: I just told him to use `/`.

Comment: But a path starting with `/` makes it an absolute path to a file in the root folder of the file system. Which part of that don't you get?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this still didn't solve my problem. It gives me Error:(21, 62) java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Check screen shot. And verify if your file is in path of package? In screen shot, see left side file.